# Firefox Video Playback: webm video recognized as type video/quicktime

Tags: html, firefox, video, webm

I am trying to play a webm video on my page using Firefox.  This is what my code looks like (I've removed the actual amazon s3 video path below, but these videos play fine when I open them directly in the browser):

```
<video controls>
   <source src="https://..s3.amazonaws.com/video/video_path/145/Untitled.webm" class="339" id="video_339" type="video/webm">
   <source src="https://..s3.amazonaws.com/video/video_path/145/Untitled.mp4" class="339" id="video_339" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

In my Firefox console, I'm getting the error

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "video/quicktime" is not supported. Load of media resource https://..s3.amazonaws.com/video/video_path/145/Untitled.webm failed. @ http://0.0.0.0:3000/projects/10/steps
```

Why is it recognizing the webm video as a quicktime video?

Comment: I've found that it's because on Amazon S3, the content type is automatically set as video/quicktime.  Is there a way to change this default?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618168/amazon-s3-is-not-serving-files-correctly

Comment: thanks, it turns out it's an issue with carrierwave not setting the right content type.