# Jekyll setting css mime type incorrectly

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, jekyll, mime

My version of Jekyll on Ubuntu Linux is not adding the correct mime type to a .css file in the _site/css/ directory.  I found this out because it causes errors when uploading site to AWS S3 bucket and the site won't render properly.

Here is what I've done:

1. created a new jekyll site `jekyll new s3upload`
2. build the site `jekyll build`
3. serve the site `jekyll serve`

and it serves fine, renders correctly in the browser, however the newly created file, main.css in _site/css directory has a mime type set as text/plain.  If I then upload it to an amazon web services bucket, to be served it fails because it needs the mime type to be set correctly to text/css.

Is this a bug in Jekyll, or how can I correct it so it creates the new .css file with the correct text/css mime type?

Relative noob here.

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll doesn't care about mime types. 
It's server's job.

If you `jekyll serve`, load the page in your favorite browser, hit `f12 -> network`, you will see that your css is served as `text/css` by WEBrick web server.

Now, in your file explorer, `file->properties`, you see that your css has a `text/plain` mime type. It is operating system point of view. This has nothing to do with serving the file.

Nevertheless, you can try to :

- Open `/etc/mime.types`
- Look for the line : `text/css     css`
- If it doesn't exists, add it.
- Do a `jekyll build` Reload to AWS bucket

If AWS still serve your css as `text/plain`, the problem is on the AWS side and you can start googling about *aws bucket mimetype problem*, see [Amazon S3 is not serving files correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618168/amazon-s3-is-not-serving-files-correctly)

Comment: Thanks David, I realise that Jekyll doesn't care, but it produces the new .css file in _site/css with the incorrect mime type (text/plain), and then when I upload it, it doesn't render properly.  I can change it manually on AWS S3 bucket but want to fix the problem and avoid this.  The text/css is set correctly in my  /etc/mime.types file.